# Cancelling a javaScript event from a UIWebViewDelegate

Tags: ios

Before I deem my weak-long custom re-implementation of UITextView (using an UIWebView in designMode) useless, is there any way to handle/cancel javaScript onKeyUp, etc. events?

AFAIK there is only messaging via -shouldLoadRequest: &  stringByEvaluatingScriptWithString:. However, these calls are asynchronous and the javaScript event handler has already exited it's function by the time stringByEvaluatingScriptWithString: is performed thus event cancellation methods do not work.

If not for this capability, implementing shouldReplaceCharactersInString: seems impossible. :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check my open source implementation of a "safari like" browser :
https://github.com/sylverb/CIALBrowser

In this one, I did reimplement the long tap handling, and to disable the standard one, I use this :

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) sender
{
    // Disable the defaut actionSheet when doing a long press
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I thought I set SO to send me email updates but I never received any. I'll try to look over this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe in your case you basically disconnected the js event handler and instead handled iOS touch event natively.

Comment: In my case iOS doesn't allow key events to be handled natively so that wouldn't work.